# Не работает setInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

Вот в этом коде не работает `setInterval()`. Функция вызывается сама по себе, но `setInterval` не работает:

```
$(function () {
    Screen = document.getElementById('gameFill');
    ctx = Screen.getContext("2d");
    clear();
    Config();
    renderSprite();
    setInterval(renderSprite,50);

});

function renderSprite() {

  skillet.img.onload = function () {

    clear();

    ctx.drawImage(skillet.img,skillet.step,80,60,80,50,50,100,100);
    skillet.step += 50;
    if(skillet.step == 400){
      skillet.step = 0;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Как вы определили что `setInterval` не работает? Функция же ничего не делает.

Comment: Делает я когда вызываю функцию она рисует но когда я вызываю ее через setInterval то она не рисует

Comment: @vadimuha - функция `renderSprite` не рисует, она только назначает обработчик `skillet.img.onload`

Comment: Она рисует, она не работает только когда я ее вызываю в setInterval

Comment: Спасибо уже разобрался

Comment: Что-то мне подсказывает, что не разобрались. В этом коде функция `recalcSprite` может рисовать только если сильно повезёт и только один раз

Comment: Нет она хорошо рисует

Answer (score 0):

Может вам это пригодиться, но рендерить через setInterval это не самое, мягко говоря, "правильно решение" обратите внимание на RequestAnimationFrame.С простор интернета :"Все зависит от частоты кадров вашего браузера и компьютера (обычно это 60 кадров в секунду). Ключевым отличием является то, что вы просите браузер выполнить функцию при первой возможности, а не с заданным интервалом. Еще одно достоинство такого подхода в том, что браузеры могут снизить requestAnimationFrame в зависимости от нагрузки, видимости элемента и состояния батареи." и это малая часть преимущества над setInterval`om